# Lisp recursion not working fine

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm working on a Lisp project for a college class, so I'm just starting to code in this language.
We were asked to implement a Lisp library to manage monomials and polynomials. 
Monomials are rappresented as: (M coefficient total-deegre (vars-and-powers)) e.g. *3ywt^3 is (M 3 5 ((V 3 T) (V 1 W) (V 1 Y)))*.
I'm not sure about how the implementation of the function which has to return a list of the variables in M. I've already defined a function to get the *vars-and-powers*, called *varpowers*.
My idea is: I'm using the list returned by *varpowers* to get the variables using the *last* function. Here is my code:

```
(defun var-of (m)
  (setq a (varpowers m))
  (cond ((null a) nil)
        (t (cons (last (car a))
                 (var-of (cdr a))))))
```

I guess the recursion is not working because everytime var-of is called in the last line *a* is redefined and its *car* is always the same (*(V 3 T)*). How can I fix this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `a` is never defined anywhere. It is an undefined variable. In this case a global undefined variable.

Comment: Rainer: `a` is defined with `setq`.

Comment: May be make the `var-of` function tail recursive. You are using `cons`.

Comment: @kadaj What Rainer Joswig meant is that the variable is undefined before the first call to `VAR-OF`, thus the `SETQ` creates a global variable, which most likely is not what was intended. It should use `LET` to create a local variable.

Comment: @ jkiiski thanks for the advice, I'm replacing SETQ with LET  
@kadaj I'm trying to think of an implementation but I guess my Lisp knowledge is still too weak

Comment: SETQ does not define any variables. The exact effect of using SETQ on an undefined variable is undefined. ;-) You would need to introduce variables in the parameter list of a function, using LET/LET*, or other constructs which create local variables. Global variables are defined with DEFVAR or DEFPARAMETER. For more info you should look at Lisp tutorial/book or the Common Lisp Hyperspec.

Comment: Have you previously used Python?  (I'm just curious, this isn't a rhetorical question!)

Answer (score 4):

Change `setq` by `let`:

```
(defun var-of (m)
  (let ((a (varpowers m)))
      (cond ((null a) nil)
            (t (cons (last (car a))
                     (var-of (cdr a)) )))))
```

Comment: @Marco, In this example, you could get rid of `a` completely: `(defun var-of (m) (cond ((null m) nil) (t (cons (last (car m)) (var-of (cdr m))))))`. Note: I've added this as a comment rather than a separate answer because Leo's answer covers an important distinction that is valuable outside of this limited example.